# Since + past perfect OR From + past simple

Tags: meaning

Which one is correct?

> 1 Since he was a teenager, he had always aspired to live alone as soon
> as he started working.
>
> (1a Since he had been a teenager, he had always aspired to live alone
> as soon as he started working.)

OR THIS ONE

> 2 From the time he was a teenager, he always aspired to live alone as
> soon as he started working.

Comment: #1a is unlikely, because there's no *need* to use the Perfect verb form, so usually we *wouldn't*. And #2 isn't idiomatic, either.

Comment: Imho, the most natural form includes an initial "intensifier": [***Ever since he was a teenager,**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Since+I+was+a%2CEver+since+I+was+a%2CSince+I+had+been+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) he had always...* In that linked chart it looks as if including ***Ever*** before ***since*** occurs about 50% of the time. But it's really much more common than that, because many matches there without ***ever*** are for ***since = because.***

Comment: I don't understand. At first you said "1a is unlikely, because there's no need to use the Perfect verb form" but then you said "Ever since he was a teenager, he had always...". But your approved version includes the perfect form.

Comment: It's normal to include the Perfect ***once*** in such constructions, but you don't need to use it ***twice***, as in your *Since he **had been** a teenager...*

Answer (score 1):

These sentences are all a bit awkward and confusing. Both the word choice and sentence structure must be improved for this to make sense.

You should see "since he was a teenager" as "[ever] since he was a teenager." This is a period of years, which is continuous. But later in the sentence, you say "as soon as he started working," which is a moment in time. And "always" is continuous, again. This is confusing if not ungrammatical.

It seems like the person, ever since his teenage years, had a desire to be self-sufficient -- to get a job and live alone. "Always" is unnecessary because it's already implied by the phrase "From the time." If you reverse the order of "live alone" and "find work," suddenly the sentence seems more natural.

> Ever since he was a teenager, he aspired to find work and live alone.

> Since his teenage years, he aspired to find work and live alone.

> From the time he was a teenager, he aspired to find work and live alone.

Answer (score 0):

*I have decided to answer my own question to make sure that I understand the issue correctly.*

**There are three situations.**

**The first** one is when the speaker hasn't finished university yet but can do it in the future.

> 1 Ever since he was a teenager he has always aspired to live alone as
> soon as he started working.

**The second** one is when the speaker didn't finish it.

**The third** one is when the speaker finished it.

> 2+3 Ever since he was a teenager he always aspired to live alone as
> soon as he started working.
>
> Ever since he was a teenager he had always aspired to live alone as
> soon as he started working.

Comment: You're trying to say too much in one sentence. That's the real problem. Why talk about three different periods of time in one sentence? It would be confusing in any language.